# Using MinTTY via Teamviewer to type backslash, pipe and at?

Tags: windows-10, teamviewer, git-bash, msys2

**Background:** Git Bash from Git for Windows uses MinTTY as the standard terminal emulator. Git Bash is built on a variant of MSYS2.

When using such a Git Bash MinTTY window, certain characters will not get properly "sensed" and simply get ignored when attempting to type them. Notably `|`, `\` and `@` are affected, which is quite annoying when working with Bash.

The [mintty(1) page](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html) even mentions TeamViewer, albeit with a seemingly unrelated setting (only <kbd>Shift</kbd> is involved):

> **Allow delay for AltGr detection** (CtrlAltDelayAltGr=0)
>
> Some software managing and providing keyboard input does not handle AltGr properly; particularly TeamViewer is known for buggy behaviour as it does not provide Ctrl and Menu virtual key codes like Windows does. With this option, some delay in milliseconds (suggested 16 or 20) can be allowed to detect a Ctrl+Menu sequence as AltGr.

The current workaround is to type those characters somewhere else and then paste them via the clipboard. However, it's cumbersome.

**Question:** Is there a way to teach MinTTY to behave in conjunction with TeamViewer as it does without? Meaning: the typing of `|`, `\` and `@` causes these characters to be recognized by MinTTY.

---

This is with a US keyboard layout on the (TeamViewer) client and server side, but I have reports that other keyboard layouts are equally affected. Client and server side are in all cases either Windows 10 or Windows 11.